# how to create array of images on a canvas using thread?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-animation

I am developing a game that uses different images.I want to set that image as background. And want to change that image after some interval. Seeing as you can't delete an individual image I want to clear the canvas and redraw the images from an array of images. My question is how do you create an array that is accessible from the onDraw method? And how do i call that onDraw method in thread so that background get changed. ?

Code for thread class :

```
private class CanvasThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private boolean isRun = false;

        public CanvasThread(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            this.surfaceHolder = holder;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            this.isRun = run;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Canvas c;

            while (isRun) {
                c = null;
                try {
                    c = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (this.surfaceHolder) {
                        DrawCanvas.this.onDraw(c);
                        // postInvalidate();

                    }
                } finally {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public class DrawCanvas extends SurfaceView implements Callback {
    private CanvasThread canvasThread;
    private int cnt = 0;
    private int[] drawable = { R.drawable.freevector_grass_sky1,
            R.drawable.freevector_grass_sky2, R.drawable.freevector_grass_sky3,
            R.drawable.freevector_grass_sky4, R.drawable.freevector_grass_sky5,
            R.drawable.freevector_grass_sky6_5,
            R.drawable.freevector_grass_sky6, R.drawable.freevector_grass_sky7,
            R.drawable.freevector_grass_sky8, R.drawable.freevector_grass_sky9,
            R.drawable.freevector_grass_sky10 };

    public DrawCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
    }

    public DrawCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        this.canvasThread = new CanvasThread(getHolder());
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public DrawCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    public void startDrawImage() {
        canvasThread.setRunning(true);
        canvasThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean retry = true;
        canvasThread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                canvasThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stubfor

        Bitmap sweet = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                drawable[cnt]);
        canvas.drawColor(color.black);
        canvas.drawBitmap(sweet, 0, 0, null);

    }
```

In my MainActivity Code:

```
if(!isDrawn) {
                DrawCanvas mycanvas = (DrawCanvas)findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView01);
                mycanvas.startDrawImage();
                isDrawn = true;
            }
```

Comment: You can't delete an individual image, explain.

Comment: means we need to redraw image on canvas. we can't delete.